# There is a quote from Brene Brown which I don't understand

Tags: meaning, quotes, concept

I know the meaning of every word in it, but I can't fully understand it. The quote is:

> “The ability, to hold something we’ve done or failed to do, up against who we want to be, is incredibly adaptive. It’s uncomfortable but it’s adaptive.”

I perceive its meaning to be: Ability to holding our past works against what we want to be.

But this is meaningless!  What is its meaning?

Comment: My interpretation is 'learn from your mistakes'. You may be interested in our sister site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the opposite of your interpretation.

The ability to look critically at our past is incredibly helpful in making us adapt.  It's uncomfortable but helpful.

The key here is the meaning of [adaptive:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptive)

> providing, **contributing to**, or marked by adaptation : arising as a result of adaptation

Comment: How it help to adapt?!

Comment: Whatever doesn't kill you makes you stronger

Comment: Excellent answer man. :)

Comment: Before this quote she was telling about correlation of feeling of shame and addiction,... . I wonder why this phrase have no correlation with the previous phrase?!

Comment: It make you stronger, but it doesn't relate to comparing it with what you want to be, I think that killing quote focus is more on experience achieved.

Comment: Adaptation is the process of becoming stronger or better. Learning how you have failed to achieve that is the only way to get better. It's uncomfortable, but it's what you must do to succeed.